# How to score the consistency of angles?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, geometry, trigonometry

I'm averaging angles by averaging their coordinates after placing them on a unit circle. I read that the length of the resulting point or centroid/center of mass is an indicator of the consistency of these angles. This makes sense in my head, that two exactly opposite angles would average to the (0,0) giving a length of 0; and that two exactly identical angles would give a unit vector.

However, I am struggling to interpret this value and am looking for if anybody knows of any guiding principles or published heuristics for this? E.g. the value does not seem to linearly represent consistency. It seems in my head that only lengths very close to 1.0 indicate good consistency and that a bunch of points that differ by more than 90deg can still give a centroid with a length >0.9.

Does anybody know of any theory or guidance on this? I don't want to blindly apply arbitrary transformations (e.g. y=1000^(x-1)) to this to make it a more intuitive 'score for consistency'.

Have I taken the wrong turn and there's a better way to score the agreement of these angles?

Comment: Interesting question, although it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. You might consider looking at distributions for circular data; I think the most common one is called the von Mises distribution. You could find the parameters for a von Mises distribution, and then you would have an estimate of the middle of it, and how much the data are spread around that. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it *can* be an indicator, but it's pretty much useless because there are infinitely many arrangements that break that assumption. For example, using the polygonal center:

```
(x,y) = (0,0)
for all p in points:
  (x,y) += p
center = (x,y)
```

We can trivially construct "problem cases":

[image]

(showing a bit of polygon reduction that, if we kept going, would eventually converge on the center).

The distance from the center of the circle to the polygon's center is zero here, but I'd struggle to call these angles consistent, uniform, evenly spaced, etc.

A much better indicator would be to determine the angle for each arc between points on your circle, and then calculate the sum of errors between each arc and what the "perfect" angle would be (which is just 2pi divided by however many points you have):

```
n = points.length
tau = 2 * pi
perfect = tau / 2
error = 0
maxError = (n-2) * perfect + TAU;
for all p in points:
  a = p
  b = points.first if p is last, otherwise p.next
  # use clockwise angles:
  angle = (atan2(a.y*b.x - a.x*b.y, a.x*b.a + a.y*b*y) + tau) % tau
  error += abs(perfect - angle)
error = error / maxError
```

The closer to zero *that* number is (which will be between 0 and 1), the closer to perfectly distributed your points are. With the maximum error based on the fact that the most "off" your points can be is if all of them lie on top of each other, so that each arc is off by the entire `perfect` amount, and the last arc from your last point to your first point is off by "the entire circle, minus `perfect`".

For instance, if we tie `error` to how red we fill the circle, we get something much more useful:

[image]